# Convert NSMutableData into NSURL for video in ios

Tags: ios, photolibrary

In socket stream while receiving data, I am able to get `NSMutableData` into image and able to save in photos but not able to convert `NSMutableData` into video

for Image I'm doing

```
UIImage *imagess = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:received];
//dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imagess, nil, nil, nil);
});
```

Somebody help me for same thing for video ?

Comment: This code won't compile in its current state.

Comment: @max_ ,i'm saving image in background thread

Comment: A line of your code is uncommented, I'd be surprised if it saved, let alone compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to save the video as a local file.

```
NSData *receivedData;
…
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"movie.mp4"];
[receivedData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Then you can use UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum function to save the video file to Photo roll.

```
NSURL movieURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(movieURL)){
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(movieURL, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: we need to create movie.mp4 file before doing this or it will creat automatically ?

Comment: UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum function needs an file path URL. But in the example [receivedData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];  function is already creating the local file so you should be fine.

Comment: file saving @cekisakurek but not finding in device ? can  you suggest where it was stored ?

Comment: if you NSLog(@"%@", movieURL); the file should be there.

Comment: thanx @cekisakurek :) its work but can you suggest me that its saving in application document but can save directly to camera roll ?